# MariaDB 5.5 on Zabbix

Tags: mariadb-5.5

it is a pleasure for me joining your community.
I read a lot of posts trying to figure how to solve some problems.
I'm facing with some performance issues about MariaDB on zabbix.

First of all, the hardware is based on NetApp HCI full SSD.
The VM got 80GB 12core of virtual resources.
The Database is about 500GB and actually it is parametrized as follow:

```
max_connections = 110
slow_query_log=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=32G
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table = ON
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 32
innodb_stats_on_metadata = OFF
thread_cache_size = 512
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = 0
join_buffer_size = 512M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
tmp_table_size = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
innodb_io_capacity=2000
open_files_limit=65535
table_open_cache=10240
```

##### Zabbix is under slow performances with the "Configuration syncer" and "History syncer" services

i get a lot of slow queries like:

```
Time: 210730 18:01:28
User@Host: zabbixfe[zabbixfe] @ app-p-zabbix-fe02 [1.1.1.2]
Thread_id: 1225328  Schema: zabbix  QC_hit: No
Query_time: 187.665202  Lock_time: 0.000123  Rows_sent: 80  Rows_examined: 99314556
SET timestamp=1627660888;
SELECT g.groupid,g.name FROM hstgrp g WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM rights r WHERE g.groupid=r.id AND r.groupid IN (13,15) GROUP BY r.id HAVING MIN(r.permission)>0 AND MAX(r.permission)>='2') AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM hosts h,items i,graphs_items gi,graphs gr,hosts_groups hg WHERE hg.hostid=h.hostid AND h.status IN (0,1) AND hg.hostid=i.hostid AND i.itemid=gi.itemid AND gi.graphid=gr.graphid AND gr.flags IN (0,4) AND g.groupid=hg.groupid) AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM hosts h,hosts_groups hg WHERE hg.hostid=h.hostid AND h.status IN (0,1) AND g.groupid=hg.groupid);

Time: 210730 18:02:24
User@Host: zabbixfe[zabbixfe] @ app-p-zabbix-fe02 [1.1.1.2]
Thread_id: 1225960  Schema: zabbix  QC_hit: No
Query_time: 162.196613  Lock_time: 0.000100  Rows_sent: 83  Rows_examined: 107770132
SET timestamp=1627660944;
SELECT g.groupid,g.name FROM hstgrp g WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM hosts h,items i,graphs_items gi,graphs gr,hosts_groups hg WHERE hg.hostid=h.hostid AND h.status IN (0,1) AND hg.hostid=i.hostid AND i.itemid=gi.itemid AND gi.graphid=gr.graphid AND gr.flags IN (0,4) AND g.groupid=hg.groupid) AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM hosts h,hosts_groups hg WHERE hg.hostid=h.hostid AND h.status IN (0,1) AND g.groupid=hg.groupid);
/usr/libexec/mysqld, Version: 5.5.65-MariaDB (MariaDB Server). started with:
Tcp port: 0  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument

Time: 210730 18:14:10
User@Host: zabbixfe[zabbixfe] @ app-p-zabbix-fe02 [1.1.1.2]
Thread_id: 18  Schema: zabbix  QC_hit: No
Query_time: 105.371170  Lock_time: 0.000070  Rows_sent: 20  Rows_examined: 542379
use zabbix;
SET timestamp=1627661650;
SELECT DISTINCT e.eventid,e.clock,e.ns,e.objectid,e.acknowledged,er1.r_eventid FROM events e LEFT JOIN event_recovery er1 ON er1.eventid=e.eventid WHERE e.source='0' AND e.object='0' AND e.objectid=90135 AND e.eventid<='139663038' AND e.value=1 ORDER BY e.eventid DESC LIMIT 20;
```

##### MysqlTuner says:

(it runs in < 1sec)

```
>>  MySQLTuner 1.7.17 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
Please enter your MySQL administrative login: root
Please enter your MySQL administrative password: [!!] Your MySQL version 5.5.65-MariaDB is EOL software!  Upgrade soon!
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
 
 
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +Aria +BLACKHOLE +CSV +FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 463.0G (Tables: 149)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0
[!!] failed to execute: SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM \`#mysql50#lost+found\`
[!!] FAIL Execute SQL / return code: 256
 
-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
 
-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!
 
-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined
 
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 3d 20h 28m 20s (597M q [1K qps], 1M conn, TX: 1650G, RX: 130G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 84% / 16%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 78.4G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 87.6G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 32.3G global + 514.7M per thread (110 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 78.5G (100.16% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 87.6G (111.70% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (5K/597M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 83% (92/110)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (5/1097879)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (15K temp sorts / 192M sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 15222
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 6% (1M on disk / 24M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (92 created / 1M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 104% (632 open / 606 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (54/65K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (757M immediate / 757M locks)
 
-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 0B
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

 
-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 8 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (5.5.65-MariaDB)
 
-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (24M used / 134M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/99.0K
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 80.0% (5 cached / 1 reads)
 
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 32.0G/463.0G
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (6.25 %): 1.0G * 2/32.0G should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 32
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.97% (272868942400 hits/ 272941485284 total)
[OK] InnoDB Write log efficiency: 96.86% (835415575 hits/ 862541514 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 27125939 writes)
 
-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[OK] Aria pagecache hit rate: 99.9% (13B cached / 7M reads)
```

###Thank you in advance
OC

Comment: can you please try and format your question so that it's easier to read? and, by the way, what _is_ your question?

Comment: "MysqlTuner says: (it runs in < 1sec)".  How much time did you take to read it?

Comment: Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.